# Pytube 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to download from Youtube using pytube,firsty I had a common issue which I think was an issue in the module itself,so I upgraded it with github,then another error occured in this code:

```
#importing the module
from pytube import YouTube

#where to Save
save_path = "E:\Mohamed's sessions\pytube"

#link of the youtube video to be downloaded
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9TcErzdoTg"


#creating an object using YouTube which was imported beofre
yt = YouTube(link)  # now this yt is an object created by the class youtube and has the attribute link

#filtering out all the files with mp4 extinsion
mp4files = yt.filter("mp4")

#setting the video name
yt.set_filename("Reiner and Bertholdt Transformation scene")

#get the video with the extension and resolution passed in the get() function
d_video = yt.get(mp4files[-1].extension,mp4files[-1].resolution)

try:
    #downloading the video
    d_video.download(save_path)
except:
    print("Some Error!")
print('Task Completed!')
```

The error title is:
AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'filter'
How Can I fix it?

Comment: If you check the documentation, it should be `yt.streams.filter()` https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simpler code that may solve the problem you have encountered:

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9TcErzdoTg"

yt = YouTube(link)  

try:
    yt.streams.filter(progressive = True, 
file_extension = "mp4").first().download(output_path = "E:\Mohamed's sessions\pytube", 
filename = "Reiner and Bertholdt Transformation scene")
except:
    print("Some Error!")
print('Task Completed!')
```

Comment: This is the single working code snippet in the entire discussion. Thank you, Mahmoud!

Answer (score 2):

The above program requires .mp4 to be added along with the file name otherwise we won't be able to open the file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).