# pytube NameError: name 'YouTube' is not defined

Tags: python, installation, pip, namespaces, pytube

I had pytube working before and I've obviously messed something up, however at the moment I can't get pytube or pytube3 to work at the most basic level.

When I run "py" to open Python, then I type in just:

```
import pytube
i = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X"
yt = YouTube(i)
```

It doesn't matter what I put for X. The third line doesn't run and fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'YouTube' is not defined
```

I've tried to fix this by:

```
pip uninstall pytube
pip uninstall pytube3
pip install pytube
```

And also by:

```
pip uninstall pytube
pip uninstall pytube3
pip install pytube3
```

I can't seem to get either one to work at the moment.

I couldn't find anyone else with this same error. [The closest I could find was this one but it seems completely different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70495354/nameerror-name-yt-is-not-defined) Any ideas what I can try to get this working?

Comment: `from pytube import YouTube`

Comment: Or, `yt = pytube.YouTube(i)`.  Personal preference.